# Spring Integration - Monitoring Tools and Techniques

Tags: spring, spring-integration, monitoring

I'm working in an application with Spring Integration, and i was wondering if there is some tools or techniques to monitoring the number of messages recived and sent, the number of failed message, and other statistics?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your google show when you search for "spring integration monitoring" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [monitoring sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/monitoring) and it's accompanying YouTube movie.

Also see [the reference manual Management chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html).